# writing a stored procedure that expects table name as parameter and create a table with that name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i want to write a stored procedure that expects name of the table as parameter and then creates a table with that name.i have tried the following piece of sql statement but it doesn't seem to work

```
create proc sp_createtable @tablename varchar(30)
as 
begin
create table @tablename
(
employees varchar(30),
)
end
```

the problem with this code is that it is generating the following error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_createtable, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@tablename'.

Comment: you need to use dynamic TSQL. lookup sp_executesql (assuming sql server; please state your RDBMS)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @FullStatement NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @FullStatement = 'create table' + @tablename + ' ( employees varchar(30))'
EXECUTE (@FullStatement)
```